# Можно ли через python скрипт запустить с++?

Tags: python, c++

### Мне нужно запустить из питоновского (который потом будет ехешным) скрипта скрипт на с++
Это как ни будь можно сделать?
может можно как то сделать срр в ехе с помощью смд?

пример:

starter_cpp.py :

```
def start_cpp_script():
    ...


start_cpp_script('hello.cpp')
#и запускается hello.cpp
```

hello.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Запускайте компилятор, компилируйте программу, а потом - скомпилированный выполнимый файл...

Comment: код срр будет меняться через код питона и его надо будет автоматически компилировать

Comment: и автоматически запускать

Comment: А есть ли в этом смысл? Вы точно не спрашиваете "какой рукой держать микроскоп" вместо "как забивать гвозди"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете пойти несколькими путями:

1. Создать динамическую библиотеку и использовать методы/классы из нее в python (примеры [тут](https://realpython.com/python-bindings-overview/) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python))
2. Скомпилировать с++ exe и запустить его из python с помощью subprocess (примеры [тут](https://www.wgilpin.com/howto/howto_cython.html) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811691/running-an-outside-program-executable-in-python))

cpp в exe можно с помощью компилятора g++, например. Либо у Вас уже есть установленный Visual Studio / QtCreator / CodeBlocks ... которые предоставляют возможность установить компилятор при установке IDE.
Если же у Вас ничего из этого нет, то вот гайд
[по шагам на все платформы](https://www.cs.odu.edu/%7Ezeil/cs250PreTest/latest/Public/installingACompiler/)
Дальше Вы уже сможете найти в интернете как им пользоваться. Дерзайте, и Вы все осилите)